# Password does not hash in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

the following code is not able to hash the user's password, and it stores the password in clear text in the database. After changing the password, I am unable to log in as the password needs to be in hash.
The following code is in my model.

```
'password_confirm'=>array(  
        'compare'    => array(
            'rule'      => array('password_match', 'password', true),
            'message'   => 'Password does not match',
            'required'  => true,
        ),
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Confirm password is empty',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true)
    ),

    'password'=>array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Password is empty',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true)
    )

function password_match($data, $password_field, $hashed = true)
    {
        $password         = $this->data[$this->alias][$password_field];
        $keys             = array_keys($data);
        $password_confirm = $hashed ?
              Security::hash($data[$keys[0]], null, true) :
              $data[$keys[0]];
        return $password === $password_confirm;
    }
```

The following code is in my user_controller

```
function change_password(){
        #CURRENTLY NOT WORKING
    $this->layout = "mainLayout";
    $in_user_id = $id = $this->Auth->user('id');

    if($this->data){
        $this->User->validate['password_confirm']['compare']['rule'] =
        array('password_match', 'password', false);

        $this->User->set($this->data);
        $this->User->useValidationRules('ChangePassword');
        if($this->User->validates()){
            $this->data['User']['id']=$in_user_id;
            $this->User->save($this->data,array('validate'=>false));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it stores the password in clear text"?  I don't see anywhere in this function where it should store anything.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the data you are passing to that function, also, what is the content of `$this->data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model and validation function are only checking that the password and confirm_password inputs match.  At no point does it alter the data to hash the input value.

After you validate your input, and before you save your model, you need to hash the password input.  Something like this:

```
$this->data[ 'User' ][ 'Password' ] = Security::hash( $this->data[ 'User' ][ 'Password' ], null, true );
```

Comment: where should this be placed in? the model or controller?

Comment: You can do it in your controller or in the model's [`beforeSave` callback function](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1052/beforeSave).

Comment: The model's beforeSave is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use the field name "password" in cake1.3 due to its automatic.
use a different field and rename it prior to saving.

if you want to use a cleaner approach, consider using a behavior:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/