# cakephp not hashing passwords the same

Tags: php, cakephp, hash, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to write a password reset function for my site in CakePHP. I've tried using `$auth->hashPasswords`, `$auth->password`, and even `Security::hash`, but nothing is hashing it correctly. I tried logging in with foobar, noting the hash used to try and log in: `cfb9fabf02497f9090cbba6b03da4764212cea407`,

but the reset makes foobar hashed into `5f4bb4b693725cea09cc7fc20603273f665534d8`.

What am I doing wrong?

my code:

```
$this->data['Player']['password'] = $this->Auth->password($this->data['Player']['password']);
$this->Player->save($this->data);
```

Comment: I'm not a cakephp user, but it sounds like it's using an internal salt to hash the password, which would completely change the hash.

Comment: I believe it automatically hashes any field called 'password' - so if you're hashing it again, that would mess it up.

Comment: So you are saying one it using the salt and the other isn't? I've checked the internal code, and they LOOK like they SHOULD be using it, but how can I tell for sure?

Comment: @Dave it wasn't automatically before, but now that you mention it, I did add the username field. Let me try removing it

Comment: @Dave that did it. make it an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: answer added - glad that helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, if you have a 'username' and 'password' field (in CakePHP 1.3 or prior), the field called "password" gets automatically hashed.  So when you do it manually, you're actually hashing it twice.

You can either rename it to something else like "password1", "mypass", "toiletpaper"...etc, which would keep it from being auto-hashed, or you can remove your additional hash.

Comment: this was what worked. The reason it DIDN'T work for me initially though, was I didn't have a username also. Automatic hashing ONLY works when a username AND password are both provided. I was only providing a password.

Comment: As a point of interest for future users, this applies to cake 1.3 (and presumably older versions). Automatic password hashing no [longer applies](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords) in **2.0**.

Comment: one should also note that his has been covered in quite a few previous questions - to only link one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857168/password-does-not-hash-in-cakephp